# Getting an error while push to master on heroku server meteor

Tags: meteor, heroku

I am getting following error while push to master heroku server meteor

```
Building Meteor app with ROOT_URL: http://****.herokuapp.com
remote: Errors prevented bundling:
remote: While minifying app code:
remote: packages/minifyStdJS_plugin.js:113:28: UglifyJS minification error: 
remote: 
remote: SyntaxError: Unexpected token name «i», expected punc «;» at
remote: node_modules/joi/lib/index.js line 185
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: It looks like you have a javascript syntax error in the `joi` package, file `index.js`, line 185.

Comment: Yes, how could fix it?

Comment: By changing the JS code to fix the syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using "Joi" and "joi-validation-strategy" for validation. Joi is not ES6 compatible, so error happened while uglify the package.

So i have changed my packages "Joi" to "joi-browser" and "joi-validation-strategy" to "joi-browser-validation-strategy". "joi-browser" is ES6 compatible.

https://github.com/jeffbski/joi-browser

https://github.com/clarkeandrew/joi-validation-strategy